# Specify directory to find stdafx.h in vcxproj file

Tags: c++, msbuild

I've been making a vcxproj file from scratch to get a better understanding of msbuild.  My project structure essentially looks like this:

```
$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\src\main.cpp
$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\src\stafx.cpp    
$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\include\stdafx.h
```

I was under the assumption by defining this in my vcxproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\include\stdafx.h" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Would allow my to call `#include "stdafx.h"` from `main.cpp` without having to specify the relative path (e.g. `#include ..\include\stdafx.h`).  But when I build my project, I get a failed message saying that msbuild can't find `stdafx.h`:

```
"C:\Projects\SDL2plusplus\SDL2PlusPlus.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  C:\Projects\SDL2plusplus\src\stdafx.cpp(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h': No such file or direc tory [C:\Projects\SDL2plusplus\SDL2PlusPlus.vcxproj]
```

Is there a way I can specify the include directory in the vcxproj file as to avoid having to put the manual path in my #include directive?

Answer (score 0):

It's a ClCompile task that falls under an ItemDefinitionGroup:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
        <!--<PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>-->
        <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
        <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\include;C:\vs_dev_lib\SDL2-2.0.8\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
```